# Regex: unwanted char

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string with x occurences of `"<DATE>"` which has to be replaced, that is simple.
If there is a `"\"` in front (`"\<DATE>"`) it musn't be replaced, simple, too:

```
[^\\]<DATE>
```

But then the string `"<DATE>"` isn't a match anymore...

```
[^\\]?<DATE>
```

But now of course the string `"\<DATE>"` is a match because the backslash is now ignored...

I tried the lookbehind `(?<!...)`, but that is not able to work with dynamic lengths...
Is there a way to do it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K<DATE>`

Comment: Or use [`"\\<DATE>"|("<DATE>")`](https://regex101.com/r/uc93Km/1) alternation to capture what you want

Comment: Darn, you are fast! 1.) Thank you to @Zenoo for editing my mess!

Comment: Do I get it right that `<DATE>` in ``\\<DATE>`` should get matched?

Comment: 2.) if @WiktorStribiżew would make his comment an answer I could set this to solved. And I of course want to than Wiktor for his stupendously fast and working answer. 
No I have to study it to see how it works :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, if it's "\<DATE>" I want no match, exactly as your regex works inn my very first tests... :)

Comment: My first comment implies there are escape sequences. If there are none, you need just `(?<!\\)<DATE>`

Comment: Thank you, then it was just the \K! Now I understand what it does, really useful! Thank you very much!

Comment: Q: is backslash escaped with a backslash? Can the string contain escaped backslashes? For example, `my $string = "\\\\<Data>";`

Comment: @shawnhcorey Yes, and to match an aribitary number (0+) of escaped backslashes before `<DATA>` you'd do (as in one of the previous examples): `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*<DATA>`. The negative lookbehind is necessary because if the number of consecutive backslashes is odd, the last one is not escaped. Furthermore, if doing substitution, make sure to also put back the escaped backslashes, like: `s¤(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)<DATA>¤$1<REPLACEMENT>¤g`.

Comment: Are the `""` part of the string or an edit artefact?

Comment: @simbabque they are not part of the string

Comment: I can't understand what worked for you in the end. Please clarify if you need to handle escape sequences or not.

Comment: This worked: (?<!\\)\K<DATE>  I add tried this before, but without the \K it didn't work. So I thank for the solution! 

Comment: Why not `s#(?<!\\)<DATE>#XXX#g` ?

Comment: @Silvar Agreed. Was just trying to clarify what the OP wanted.

Comment: @art_varn without the \K the expression doesn't work at the beginning of the line...

Comment: @TedBear `(?<!\\)\K<DATE>` is the same as `(?<!\\)<DATE>`. The `\K` has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my top comment to an answer since it was helpful.

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K<DATE>
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\\)` - a location in the string that is not immediately preceded with a backslash (a backslash is matched with a double backslash in the regex pattern)
- `(?:\\{2})*` - a non-capturing group that matches 0 or more sequences of double backslashes
- `\K` - a match reset operator that zeros out the current match value
- `<DATE>` - a literal substring that is matched and consumed (=added to the match value and the regex index is advanced).